# How to change desktop resolution from terminal for KDE5 running on Wayland?

Tags: wayland, amd-graphics, kde5

Using KDE5 on Arch Linux with Wayland. I hit apply when changing resolutions to see which one would be suitable, small desktop resolution and then my monitor said it was unsupported.

How do I revert/reset it from a terminal?

Comment: Found this cli tool that does it - https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/6bj8lk/changing_resolution_from_cli_on_gnome_wayland/ (untested)

Comment: That doesn't work with KDE. Service unavailable; the name org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig was not provided by any service files.

Comment: Sorry about that, I missed you were on KDE, that's a GNOME solution.

Comment: Also, renaming the kde4 folder doesn't fix it: `mv ~/.kde4 ~/.kde4.old`

Comment: I could find nothing that shows how to do this, very perplexing, and I do not have any of this locally to try.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a CLI solution:

1. Make sure the user in question is logged off (CTRL + Alt + Del, then enter)
2. Go to a TTY terminal, login as that user,
3. Run `mv ~/.kde4 ~/.kde4.old` then `startx`
4. Go back to the main display (CTRL + Alt+  F7), login, and it should display  the default resolution.
5. Close the x session
6. Open the display settings from the system settings (systemsettings5).
7. Reset the settings, select enable the main display, then click apply.
8. Go to any terminal and enter `mv ~/.kde4.old ~/.kde4`
9. Reset the display settings again then click on apply or OK.

Comment: Renaming the ~/.kde4 folder then restarting, on paper, seemed to be the solution, but without all of these other steps, it didn't work.